# How to restrict two digits after decimal point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I need to allow user to type only two digits after the decimal point .

I just tried the following code but i am not getting exact result.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if([sep count] >= 2)
    {
        NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
        return !([sepStr length]>2);
    }

    return YES;
}
```

i am getting following result  for above code: 123.12.1233

But i need  result like  1)1234.12 2)12.23

Note: I am using number keypad as keyboard input view.

Comment: If you want pure decimal textfield(not allow other characters then number or dot,not allow dot at first position, and not allow more then two character after dot ) then try my code.

Comment: good question.. am upvoting. i also need this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have have modified your code. Try this

```
NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if([sep count] >= 2)
{
    NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
    if (!([sepStr length]>2)) {
        if ([sepStr length]==2 && [string isEqualToString:@"."]) {
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As in most languages the format is

```
%.2f
```

For Example

```
NSString* NumberStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", yourFloatValue];
```

`%.02f` tells the formatter that you will be formatting a float (%f) and, that should be rounded to two places.

Example:

```
%f = 5.000000
%.f = 5
%.02f = 5.00
```

Comment: I need to restrict while typing itself .

Answer (score 1):

Below method will not allow `more than two digits after dot`, It will not allow `dot at first position or as first character`, It will not allow any character rather then `number or dot`

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{




NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];

// allow backspace
if (range.length == 0 && [string length] == 0) {
    return YES;
}

if ([string isEqualToString:@"."] ){

    if (range.location == 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    if(dotLocation == 0){

        dotLocation = range.location;
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }

}
if (range.location == dotLocation && string.length==0) {

    dotLocation = 0;

}

if (dotLocation > 0 && range.location > dotLocation+2) {
    return NO;
}


NSString *newValue = [[textField text] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
newValue = [[newValue componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
textField.text = newValue;

return NO;
}
```

In this method `dotLocation` is instance variable of type `int`. Just declare instance Variale `int dotLocation` something,

```
  @interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
 {

 int dotLocation;
 }
```

That's it and this method will work fine.

Second thing make sure that you have set your textField's delegate to self in `viewDidload` like,

```
 yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using Regex like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSString *expression = @"^[0-9]*((\\.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?$";
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
    return numberOfMatches != 0;
}
```